# How to get a voronoi diagram's edges and their associate sites in MATLAB?

Tags: matlab

I created a voronoi diagram. Now what I want to do is to store every edge and its two associated sites. For example, I got the diagram as the following:
[image]

Say I want to store the edge `(v4, v5)` and its associate sides, `X3` and `X8`.

I used

```
[VX,VY] = voronoi(X(:,1),X(:,2));
```

to create this  voronoi diagram. Thus I could use `VX` and `VY` to get all the edges. However, I do not really know how to get the edge's associate sides. In other words, I can get the edge `(v4, v5)`, but I have no idea to achieve its associate sites,`X3` and `X8`, and make edge `(v4, v5)` pointed to  `X3` and `X8`.

Could someone give me some ideas please?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use C array of Voronoi cells from (see here http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/voronoin.html)

```
[V,C] = voronoin(X)
```

You can also use (see exmple here http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/math/voronoi-diagrams.html)

```
dt = delaunayTriangulation(X);
[V,R] = voronoiDiagram(dt)
```

Comment: Is there a spelling mistake? The last two chars. I can't find the function `voronoin`. [voronoi()](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/matlab/ref/voronoi.html) exists.

Comment: Nope, it exists. Please, check the link http://www.mathworks.nl/help/matlab/ref/voronoin.html

Comment: Hmm... It's strange that it didn't come up in my search.